# Combining two leaflet extensions?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox, marker, leaflet.markercluster

I'm asking myself how would it work to combine two leaflet extensions.

I'm using the providers Extension here: https://github.com/leaflet-extras/leaflet-providers
Creating a map like this:

```
L.tileLayer.provider('Wikimedia').addTo(map);
```

Now I would like to change the style of it with the color Filter Extension here: 
https://github.com/xtk93x/Leaflet.TileLayer.ColorFilter

```
let map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 14);

let myFilter = [
    'invert:100%',
    'saturate:300%',
    'sepia:10%',
];

let myTileLayer = L.tileLayer.colorFilter('https://maps.wikimedia.org/osm-intl/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '<a href="https://wikimediafoundation.org/wiki/Maps_Terms_of_Use">Wikimedia</a>',
    filter: myFilter,
}).addTo(map);
```

I'm using almost all tile providers inside the provider extension for my project, so i can't just switch to a static tile layer.

Is it possible to combine these two extensions?